# Chromium snap and integrations

Tags: chromium, snap

Since Chromium moved over to snaps, bot the Plasma integration and the KeepassXC integration are broken. This is expected, because the snap is sandboxed and cannot access other programs.

I don't know a lot about snap and similar questions are unanswered. Is there a way around it, that is, can I use the slot and plug system to reenable these integrations?

This slowly becomes a deal breaker and I am considering switching browsers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the slot and plug system"? And "Plasma integration" is present in Kubuntu, not Ubuntu or any other official flavor AFAIK. Anyway, you could post in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition/11179/12 and see if people there can help.

Comment: Snaps seem to have some system to connect different sandboxed packages: https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management
And yes, Plasma integration is for PLasma. What do you mean, that I should set a KUbuntu tag? I thing this issue is more general. A program that needs connections to other programs has been sandboxed. This needs a solution.